# Firebase iOS .queryOrderedByChild and .queryEqualTo not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to filter results from a Firebase database with a structure like this one.

```
chats
    chatId
        messages
            messageId
                userId: true
```

I need two queries, one that returns only messages with existing child **userId** (if it exists it will always be true), the other that returns only messages without it.

I'm trying with this two references and observing .childAdded event:

```
let messagesWithUser = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "chats").child(chat.id).child("messages").queryOrdered(byChild: userId).queryEqual(toValue: true).ref
let messagesWithoutUser = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "chats").child(chat.id).child("messages").queryOrdered(byChild: userId).queryEqual(toValue: NSNull()).ref
```

Currently the .childAdded event returns all messages without filtering.

Comment: What are you expecting the variable *let messagesWithUser =* to contain?

Comment: The FIRDatabaseReference which I use to observe childAdded events. I expect it to trigger only for messages with the specified child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem. I was using FIRDatabaseReference instead of FIRDatabaseQuery to observe changes...

Answer (score 3):

In response to [Dmitriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4443005/dmitriy-groschovskiy):

```
func blueRewardBalance(completeBlock: (value: Double) -> Void) {
        let userRef = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        var rewardBalance : Double! = 0.00
        let purchaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Reward/\(userRef!)")
        purchaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "abc").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            let dataSnapshot = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            rewardBalance = dataSnapshot["rewardCardBalance"] as! Double!
            completeBlock(rewardBalance)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nicola. I need implement previous method into my function, but blueRewardBalance request parameters.

```
func blueRewardTransaction(purchaseValue: Double) {
        let newBalance = blueRewardBalance(completeBlock: //what I need paste here?) - purchaseValue
        let userRef = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        let firebaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        firebaseRef.child("Reward/\(userRef!)").updateChildValues(["rewardCardBalance": newBalance])
    }
```

Comment: func blueRewardTransaction(purchaseValue: Double) {
   let newBalance = blueRewardBalance(completeBlock: (value) in {
         let userRef = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
              let firebaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
              firebaseRef.child("Reward/\     (userRef!)").updateChildValues(["rewardCardBalance": newBalance])
     }
}